# Is there a null-safe comparison operator for pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When trying to create  boolean column that is True if two other column are equal and False otherwise, I noticed that Null == Null = False in spark.

```
df.withColumn('newCol', F.when(F.col('x')==F.col('y'), True).otherwise(False))
```

This: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-ref-null-semantics.html
Suggests that I could use <=> if I was using SQL syntax, but am looking to stick to pyspark sql api if I can.

```
df.withColumn('newCol', F.when(F.col('x')<=>F.col('y'), True).otherwise(False))
```

doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: check http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out `pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe.html