# find rows where columns mismatch

Tags: pyspark, filter, apache-spark-sql

How could I find rows where two columns don't equal (like you can with pandas)?

```
data = [("John", "Doe"), (None, "Doe"), ("John", None), (None, None)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["first", "last"])

df
first     last
John       Doe
null       Doe
John       null
null       null
```

Expected output:

```
first     last
John       Doe
null       Doe
John       null
```

I tried

```
df_filtered = df.filter(col("first") != col("last"))
```

Comment: did you not get the desired result using your filter code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a null-safe comparison operator for pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63835453/is-there-a-null-safe-comparison-operator-for-pyspark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get your expected output in PySpark as follows:

1. Using [`equal_null`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.equal_null.html):

   ```py
   df.filter(~equal_null(col("first"), col("last")))
   ```
2. Using [`nvl`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.nvl.html):

   ```py
   df.filter(nvl(col("first"), lit("")) != nvl(col("last"), lit("")))
   ```
3. Using [`ifnull`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.ifnull.html):

   ```
   df.filter(ifnull(col("first"), lit("")) != ifnull(col("last"), lit("")))
   ```

You can do this in many other ways like [@s.polam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8593414/s-polam) did in their answer, using `expr` or just SparkSQL. For me, the best approach is using `equal_null` because it matches your requirement exactly and doesn't require any additional literals (empty strings) like the other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below.

```
df_filtered = df.filter("nvl(first, '') <> nvl(last, '')")
```

```
+-----+----+
|first|last|
+-----+----+
|John |Doe |
|NULL |Doe |
|John |NULL|
+-----+----+
```